# Javascript Exif information only showing after the first click of image in html page

Tags: javascript, file, exif

Ok, my problem is pretty specific, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

I am making a site, in which you upload a folder of images using the FileReader() API, and they are displayed. When you click on an image, it gets maximized and, using the EXIF.pretty() from the exif-js library, you display the Exif information, along with a google map. I have a "Go Back" button that takes you back to the collection

So, the problem is, when I click a picture the first time, it shows no EXif information, but the google map can be displayed. The second time onwards, it displays everything correctly. This happens to every picture.

This is the part of the javascript where I write the EXIF to the html:

```
function writeEXIFData(image, EXIFelem) {
    var allMetaData = EXIF.pretty(image);
    console.log(image);
    var allMetaDataAside = document.getElementById(EXIFelem);
    var ExifData = document.createElement("div");
    ExifData.id = "EXIFData";
    allMetaDataAside.appendChild(ExifData);
    if (allMetaData !== "") {
        ExifData.innerHTML = allMetaData;
    } else {
        ExifData.innerHTML = "NO DATA AVAILABLE";
    }
}
```

There are 2 pictures of what the File looks as an output in console the first and second time.[The second one appears to have more information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LFXN.png) [But they are the same exact files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHNJJ.png)

So, why is this happening? I am clicking the same exact images from the same array.

Thank you.

Edit: Michael Camden: If I understood what you are asking.
This is inside my API in a return block:

```
showImage: function (index, elem, EXIFelem) {
    document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = "";
    var file = loadedImages[index];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (file) {
        return function (event) {
            // Render thumbnail.
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "maximize";
            div.innerHTML = ['<img src="', event.target.result, '" title="', encodeURI(file.name), '">'].join('');
            document.getElementById(elem).insertBefore(div, null);
        };
    }(file));
        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        TIV3446.makePreviousbtn(elem, EXIFelem);
        TIV3446.showImageDetailedExifInfo(index, EXIFelem);
        TIV3446.showImageDetailedExifWithMap(index, EXIFelem);
}

showImageDetailedExifInfo: function (index, EXIFelem) {
    EXIF.getData(loadedImages[index], writeEXIFData(loadedImages[index], EXIFelem));
}
```

Edit2: The code I sent is probably not what you were asking. There is also this:

```
    var i;
    var file;
    var reader;
    for (i = 0; i < loadedImages.length; i += 1) {
        file = loadedImages[i];
        reader = new FileReader();
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (file, index) {
            return function (event) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.className = "tile";
                div.addEventListener("click", function () {TIV3446.showImage(index, elem, EXIFelem);});
                div.innerHTML = ['<img src="', event.target.result, '" title="', encodeURI(file.name), '">', '<div class="info">', encodeURI(file.name).slice(0, -4)].join('');
                document.getElementById(elem).insertBefore(div, null);
            };
        }(file, i));
        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the click handler to gather the EXIF information? It sounds like gathering the EXIF data is an asynchronous process, that you are using in a synchronous way, but I can't be certain without your other code.

Comment: I edited my post, I don't know if you get a notification for that.

Comment: can you please add this line`console.log(allMetaData);` instead of `console.log(image);` and share the result for both cases with us?

Comment: I think you ought to delete this question and the answer as this will probably never help anyone due it being basically a syntax error, though glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Pretty stupid to be honest.

This :

```
showImageDetailedExifInfo: function (index, EXIFelem) {
    EXIF.getData(loadedImages[index], writeEXIFData(loadedImages[index],  EXIFelem));
}
```

Must be written like this:

```
showImageDetailedExifInfo: function (index, EXIFelem) {
    EXIF.getData(loadedImages[index], function () {
        writeEXIFData(loadedImages[index], EXIFelem)
    });
}
```